# Using 'master session' for site-wide cache

Tags: php, session, caching

I've been wanted to add a caching feature to my websites which persist between multiple user sessions. The idea is to be able to store the result of frequently executed queries, or calculations which also don't change very often. My main use for this is when a user hits my website, a query runs to find the page they have requested. Pages change very infrequently so I'd like to cache this result for 2-4 hours for ever user so that query doesn't have to run over and over on every pageload for every user.

What I've made is a PHP Object which stores the current session_id and whenever a read or write is made to the cache object, it closes the session with session_write_close(), starts a new session with a hardcoded session_id reads/writes to/from this hardcoded 'master' session, and then reverts to the original session_id after session_write_close()ing the master session.

Can anyone think of any issues with this approach? I wanted to avoid using anything overly sophisticated like memecache so I thought this was pretty simple, and it seems to work just fine!

Thoughts and other ideas for approaches would be appreciated!

Comment: Dan this question is a bit broad for this site.

Comment: Fair enough, I read through the guidelines and thought it was still applicable, but first post, so live and learn!

Comment: I'm glad that I found this here. It seems to be the only possibility to share actual PHP objects between sessions. I tried memcache but I need a possibility to iterate over the keys/values of my cache. This should be possible with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This solution sounds more complicated then simply using Memcache.

The main issue I have with this solution is that you are using Session to basically store cache files. PHP by default stores session in files and you are closing and opening sessions unnecessary. Here is a simpler way for you to accomplish exactly the same with better performance:

1. Check to see if your cache file is older then 2 hours using [filemtime()](http://php.net/filemtime) :

   ```
   if(filemtime($cache_file) > time()-3600*2)
   ```
2. If older you create your PHP Cache object and write it to the cache file using [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/file_put_contents) and [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize):

   ```
   file_put_contents($cache_file, serialize($cache_object))
   ```
3. If the file is younger then 2 hours then retrieve the PHP Cache object using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [unserialize()](http://php.net/unserialize)

   ```
   $cache_object = unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_file))
   ```

Comment: I like this and am currently trying it. However, I think the arguments of file_put_contents would be correct the other way around:
`file_put_contents($cache_file, serialize($cache_object))`
(according to http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Indeed, the arguments where switched, fixed now.